# Telegram sending png picture to Telegram converts it to jpg

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

Why is that when I send a png picture to telegram bot, and then download it, it becomes jpg? How to avoid it?

```
MY_USER_ID = 012345
MY_TOKEN = "12345"
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CommandHandler

updater = Updater(token=MY_TOKEN, use_context=True)

updater.start_polling()

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def create_sticker_set(update, context):

    update_dict = update.to_dict()

    sticker_file_id = update_dict["message"]["photo"][-1]["file_id"]

    print("sticker_file_id=", sticker_file_id)

    file = context.bot.get_file(update_dict["message"]["photo"][-1]["file_id"])
    filename = file.download() # it is jpg, and it must be png

    context.bot.add_sticker_to_set(MY_USER_ID, "lala_by_ibodi_bot", open(filename, "rb"), "")


msghandler = MessageHandler(Filters.photo, create_sticker_set)
dispatcher.add_handler(msghandler)
```

This code creates a handler that receives a picture and adds it to a sticker set. I want to preserve the extension of the picture so that transparent parts of the picture stayed transparent in a sticker set. And converting it to jpg makes transparent places white.

Comment: *"Stackoveflow complains that my post is mostly code, so I am writing this sentence."* Why not write more details about your actual question, since that's the point of this prompt? For example, you could write about testing sending PNG files by some other method and whether they were converted to JPG in that case; or some other way that you have determined that PNG files are supposed to work.

Comment: @kaya3 I added some explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution. When I send the file I should choose "Send as a file" instead of "Send as a photo", and it won't convert the png to jpg.

[image]

And the code presented above must have some changes:

```
# we put 
msghandler = MessageHandler(Filters.document, create_sticker_set)
# instead of instead of
msghandler = MessageHandler(Filters.photo, create_sticker_set)
```

and

```
# we put 
file = context.bot.get_file(update_dict["message"]["document"]["file_id"])
# instead of 
file = context.bot.get_file(update_dict["message"]["photo"][-1]["file_id"])
```